# Python Django How display information of logged user contained in another class in my template?

Tags: python, html, django, class, templates

I'm developing a website in Python Django. I have CustomUser class for logging and another class coach where I have information of my users. Every user are linked to coach class.

I'm trying to display in my template information of my user contained in the coach class. I have logged user and can display their `username` on my template with `{{ user.username }}`

My problem is that I am not able to display, for example, Address with `{{ coach.Adresse }}`.

Any idea how to fix this?

My models.py

```
class coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Adresse = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    Telephone = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=140, default='111')
```

My profile.html

```
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Welcome {{ user.username }} !!! {{coach.Adresse}} !!!
{% else %}
    Not logged
{% endif %}
</body>
```

my views.py

```
def Profile(request):
        return render(request, 'Profile.html')
```

Comment: Are you sending the coach variable in context? Can you show your view?

Comment: I edited my question now there is my views.py. I think that I don't send coach variable in context. I don't how to do that.

Comment: Note that in Django, the recommended style is to use  capitalised `Coach` for your model and lowercase `addresse` and `telephone` for your fields.

Comment: @Nikita what does that page display when you load it? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the `user` in the template context, you can follow the one-to-one field backwards with:

```
{{ user.coach.Adresse}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I tried your solution but It didn't work.

Comment: From the code you have posted, it should work. Perhaps there is no `coach` linked to that `user`

Comment: Are you sure the logged in user has a related `Coach` class, with an `Address`  specified ? Try printing it in your view to confirm that, or check it through the shell.

Comment: Also, make sure you have set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.CustomUser` in your settings. The recommended approach is to define the foreign key with `user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)` so that it refers to the correct model.

Comment: You were right !  My class coach was not correctly linked to user. I resolved this error and now it is working. Thank you for your help.